# Spring controller is not supporting ServerHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using ServerHttpRequest as the request parameter in my Rest Controller. But in the response I'm getting error as "No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest".

I found one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615945/spring-webflux-annotated-rest-controller-doesnt-support-serverhttprequest-as-me),  but no luck.

Rest Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/**")
public Mono <ResponseEntity< String>> clientRequests(ServerHttpRequest request) {
    Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> jsonOp =  restServices.getApiResponse();
    return jsonOp;
}
```

Log

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest.()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${reactor-netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Versions:

```
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <reactor-netty.version>0.8.6.RELEASE</reactor-netty.version>
```

Comment: Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399058/reactive-spring-does-not-support-serverhttprequest-as-parameter-in-rest-endpoint). Looks similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks Azhar but I am importing the correct class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;

Answer (score 4):

As @Brian Clozel mentioned this can be caused from the coexistece of "Spring WebFlux" and "Spring MVC" frameworks and the Spring's automate behaviour in configuring the application as a servlet-based web application ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-web-applications.spring-webflux)).

So, try to run your application as a REACTIVE web application:

//Programmatically [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(YourApp.class);
    springApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
    springApplication.run(args);
}
```

//By properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-disable-web-server)

```
spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Spring Boot reference documentation on WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux), adding both web and webflux starters means that Spring Boot will auto-configure a Spring MVC application.

This argument type cannot be resolved in this case because Spring MVC applications cannot resolve this request type.